# Magento2.1.5 Doesn't create the versionxxxxxxxx folder while static content deploy

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.5

I have installed latest `magento version 2.1.5` and configured it.

It works fine but once we run the

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Command, it doesn't create the version folder as expected.

I can see by viewing source that the content is being called via particular version like below:

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento215/pub/static/**version1489125606**/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css
```

But in `pub static` the folder **"version1489125606"** is missing.

All the files are reside directly in pub/static folder. Is there any setting to get it update?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The setting is working fine given by you. However I would like to know about to get it work proper with sign Static Files value to 'Yes'.

Comment: you can read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/view/static-process.html and  http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/static-file-signature.html about this in more detail how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello Himmat  log in admin

then go to `store->configuartion->Advanced->Developer->Static File Setting`

and  `Sign Static Files` set values to `no`

Comment: `Sign Static Files` set values to 'Yes` to create versionXXXX folder.

Comment: Yes, it is not creating the versionxxxxxxx folder in 2.1.5, seems magento default issue. Anyways, thanks guys for your time..

Comment: You are always welcome @HimmatPaliwal :)

Comment: It is not issue. This folder should not be created. Magento use rewrites to skip it.

Answer (score 1):

This folder should not be created. It is not the issue. 
Magento use rewrites to skip it.
see https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.5/nginx.conf.sample#L95 for nginx or https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.5/pub/static/.htaccess#L16 for apache

Comment: ok, but it is not getting skipped after static-content deploy.